# Ionic Framework Gulp Task and Cordova Hook

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I just started out with Ionic Framework. I got some experience with Cordova and aware of the hooks given for build scripts to be triggered.

After I run `ionic start myApp`, it created all the project files and folders for me. It also gives me the file gulpfile.js which contains a task to compile scss and put it into www/css.

When you run `cordova prepare`, it seems to use the files from www folder to build the project for different platforms but it doesn't fire up the gulp task.

My questions are:
1. How are the 2 commands related? `cordova prepare` and `gulp sass`
2. Do you feel that the www folder is like a generated folder? Does it make sense to create another app folder with all js, css files and then do all the pre-processing and copy them to www folder?
3. If number 2 is correct, should we add www folder to .gitignore?

Answer (score 0):

The `cordova prepare` command will generate all the assets including transpiling all the sass file before `cordova compile`. So for your #1 question is `gulp sass` is part of `cordova prepare` execution.

For your #2 question is Yes, the www file is part of generated file from you Ionic project prepare for compilation into native application.

For your #3 question is No, Ionic already have platforms folder in git-ignore file that host generated Cordova project.